# Add Configurable products via Admin Panel

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I want to add Simple products in the configurable product. I can't find the option for adding products in the configuration section of the configurable product. It only showing create configuration option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have not noticed this before. But you can click on the botton **configuration section** and follow the wiget and complete it. It will show you the new products combination with the attributes options you have selected. Dont worry those products are not created nor saved until you save the product.

Now you will be able to see **Add Products Manually** visible clicking on it you You can click on it and add products using it.

More information on how to create configurable products [here](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-create-configurable.html)

There is also bug reported in magento for it [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5281)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this link to add configurable product in magento2:
https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-create-configurable-product-magento-2.html

Please follow the below steps :

1. Select the Attributes
2. Enter the Attribute Values
3. Configure the Images, Price and Quantity
4. Generate the Product Configurations
5. Publish the Products
6. Configure the Shopping Cart Thumbnails (Optional)
7. Final, check your result by view the Products in your store.